# Postgres accessing JSONB elements in efficient way

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing

I have `batch_table` table, which contain `batchid` type of serial int and `data` type of JSONB, I indexed `data` column using `GIN`,

```
batchid | data
---------------------------------------------
1  | [{"year":2000,"productid":[21, 32, 5]}]
2  | [{"year":2001,"productid":[21, 39, 5]},{"year":2000,"productid":[1, 25, 5]}]
3  | NULL
4. | [{"year": 2000,"productid":[5]}
```

Now I want to get `batchid` by using following requirements 
    1. `year` = 2000 & `productid`= 5 
    2. `year` = 2000 & `productid`= (21 or 5) 
    3. `year` = 2000 & `productid`= (21 & 5)

and I tried this

```
SELECT batchid FROM batch_table WHERE (data->>'year')::int = 2000 AND (data->>'productid')::int = 5;
```

with `AND` & `OR` for other queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [containment operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to search in `jsonb` (this can even use your index):

1.

```
select *
from   batch_table
where  data @> '[{"year":2000,"productid":[5]}]';
```

2.

```
select *
from   batch_table
where  data @> '[{"year":2000,"productid":[21]}]'
or     data @> '[{"year":2000,"productid":[5]}]';
```

3.

Depending on your needs, you can use one of these:

- These will select rows, where year=2000 with productid=21 are in the same object **and** year=2000 with productid=5 are in the same object (but these objects *can* be different ones).

  ```
  select *
  from   batch_table
  where  data @> '[{"year":2000,"productid":[21]}]'
  and    data @> '[{"year":2000,"productid":[5]}]';

  select *
  from   batch_table
  where  data @> '[{"year":2000,"productid":[21]},{"year":2000,"productid":[5]}]';
  ```
- This will select rows, where year=2000 with productid=21 are in the same object **as well as** productid=5

  ```
  select *
  from   batch_table
  where  data @> '[{"year":2000,"productid":[21, 5]}]';
  ```

http://rextester.com/ZMCUME18642